py2wasm не распознано как имя командлета
На windows после установки py2wasm pip install py2wasm не могу его использовать.

py2wasm : Имя "py2wasm" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. ....

UPD: Добавил лог из рекомендаций ответа ferz
Python version 3.11.9
nuitka --version


Официальная странца этого проекта: https://pypi.org/project/py2wasm/ ->
Tutorial Setup -> Install Nuitka
python -m pip install nuitka

или
pip install nuitka

После этого
pip install py2wasm

Когда ставишь сначала nuitka, все нормально
nuitka --version
2.4.8 ...
После установки py2wasm nuitka  выдает ошибки

скинь логи ошибок

добавил в вопросе
